# Relative Imports in .py are killing me

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a unittest with the following folder structure (yes I know it's overkill, I'm just trying to learn):

```
sentence_checker
├───__init__.py
|
├───project_files
|   ├───__init__.py 
|   └───sentence_format_checker.py
|
└───tests
    ├───__init__.py
    └───test_sentence_format_checker.py
```

In my test file I have the lines:

```
import unittest
from ..project_files import test_sentence_format_checker    # also the name of the function I'm testing
```

When I run:

```
python -m unittest test_sentence_format_checker.py
```

I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent directory`.

I've tried a few different variations and tonnes of old searches on here and elsewhere but I can't get it sorted. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try doing a `cd` to progect directory before running command

Comment: that results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...`

Comment: it does, I just forgot to write it in there

Comment: `project_files` doesn't have a module named `test_sentence_format_checker`. You might need something like `from .. import project_files.sentence_format_checker` or `from ..project_files import sentence_format_checker`.

Comment: I've tried both and I just get the same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
# import module from sibling or parent directory
```

You can do this, and then use `sys.path.append(...)` again when you want to go back into your own directory. A couple extra lines but works well.

Comment: I wouldn't opt for complex directory and path manipulation. Defining the package structure seems more robust in my view.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because Python cannot determine the package structure when using relative imports. Relative imports are typically used within a package to import modules relative to the current package.

I would change it as follows:

1. Decide on the top level for your Python package. In this case, you could decide this is the directory `sentence_checker`.
2. Make sure you have an `__init__.py` in every subdirectory (which you have)
3. Use an absolute import w.r.t. the package root:

```
from project_files.sentence_format_checker import sentence_format_checker
```

4. Run the tests from the directory that is the package root. In this case, that is the directory `sentence_checker`

```
python -m unittest
```

Or to run specific these tests:

```
python -m unittest tests.test_sentence_format_checker
```

If you try to run this command from the`tests` directory itself, you will get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_checker'`

Note: If you use an IDE like PyCharm, you can mark a certain directory as Sources root, and it will then know what is the package root.